# Making a videoJS instance scale when window size changes

Tags: css, electron, video.js

This is a pretty basic question but I've been wrestling with it for days now without success.

I have an Electron desktop app which allows the user to select local videos to play. I want to be able to specify a `div` for the video and have the video's size restricted, proportionately (e.g. maintaining aspect ratio), to the size of that `div`. I also need to have the video scale if the user changes the size of the window, for example by making the app full-screen.

So far I've been able to get the video to be centered, but when the window size changes, the video stays the same size (images below).

I've tried adding the `videojs` CSS classes (vjs-16-9, vjs-4-3) and tried using `data-setup='{"fluid": true}'` but these cause the video to take over the entire window.

So the gist: how can I specify that I want the video *height* to take some percentage of the screen – say 40%, have it resolve the proper aspect ratio for its width, and then when the window size changes, have it recalculate?

---

```
   .video-center {
      margin-left: auto !important;
      margin-right: auto !important;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

---

```
  <div class="videocontent">
    <video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-hidden video-center"  controls>
    </video>
  </div>
```

Window mode:

[image]

Fullscreen mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your end goal, you want to absolutely position the video and use the parent to create padding that will mimic the video's aspect ratio.

```css
.videocontent {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* divide the video height by the width to get this percentage */
}
.videocontent video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="videocontent">
    <video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-hidden video-center"  controls>
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

## Replace **Videojs**

I suggest to remove the **Videojs**, and use the instructions below to generate the custom code.

## Set the `<video>` element *width* and *height* attributes.

```
<video width="991" height="557"></video>
```

Thought we've explicitly specify the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<video>` element. We're only going to use those values for initial determination of the correct aspect ratio. **See Javascript code below**:

## Set the parent container width to your heart's content

```
.videocontent {
    width: 80%;
    /* for horizontal centering (optional) */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

## Include **jQuery** in your page.

```
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

## Custom **Javascript** to handle the dynamic aspect ratio.

```
// Find all <video> element
var $allVideos = $('video'),

  // The element that is fluid width
  $fluidEl = $('.videocontent');

// Figure out and save the aspect ratio for each <video> element on the page
$allVideos.each(function() {

   $(this)
    // values from <video> height and width attributes
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

 });

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all <video> according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

## Credit [Fluid Width YouTube Videos](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)